# Simple string permutations question

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many sequences of 5 letters are there in which exactly two are vowels?

**My approach**

There are $5^2$ different permutations for 2 vowels and $\binom{5}{2}$ ways allocate them. There are $21^3$ ways for the remaining 3 consonants.

so it should be $\binom{5}{2} \cdot 5^2 \cdot 21^3$.

Am I right? Is there a better way to model this?

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks good to me .

Comment: The answer is correct, but if you're writing it up for homework / an exam etc., you should add that $\binom{5}{2}$ is the number of ways to allocate the *positions* of the vowels in the sequence.